# How do I detect if two text images are similar without OCR?

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to compare two images with usernames and check if both are the same. I'm not able to use OCR [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) because the usernames can have letters from two or three different languages. Because of this, Tesseract is not able to parse the text from the image. I used [ImageHash](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/imagehash) to try and figure out if the images are similar.

But when I try to compare this image:

[image: first iamge]

then ImageHash gives me a result that user name **Mustang1202** is more similar to this image than **Mustang1203**.

Is there a different way I can detect similar text in images?

Comment: You could use cognitive services by Microsoft

Comment: Since you're already using [ImageHash](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/imagehash), can you try hashing both images, then getting their distance? See [here](http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/?/archives/529-Kind-of-Like-That.html) for a quick rundown of what could work for you.

Comment: @jayg_code whist we won't know before actually trying, that kind of intuitive 'naive' comparison will often give really strange results when comparing characters as, for instance, a small 8 might be real close to '3' whilst a larger '3' would be really far from its smaller counterpart.

Comment: @jayg_code I did try getting the distance, the **Mustang1202** was closer than the **Mustang1203** distance